# Issue with installing Mercurial Activity extension

Tags: windows, mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm using Windows XP with installed Mercurial TortoiseHg on it. Now I need to install the external [activity extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ActivityExtension). I downloaded the extension and enabled it in hgrc.

When I'm try to call it using command:

```
hg activity
```

I receive the following error:

```
There are 292 changesets
Hg activity options: you need matplotlib in your python path in order to use the hg activity extension.
```

Then I installed the python 2.6 and matplotlib. So the paths of them are:

- D:\Python26\
- D:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib

Now I don't know how to tell mercurial activity extension to use matplotlib from that location? I found some explanation in the [TortoiseHg FAQ](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/0.9/faq.html), under the heading "Where do TortoiseHg extensions look for external Python modules on Windows?"

But when I do the steps that are written there I receive the same error message as above.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the approach and seems to work fine.

You will need to include the path as

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages')
```

Also see the following code @ http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/src/cf4b3dfd15ee/contrib/hg

```
# enable importing on demand to reduce startup time
try:
    from mercurial import demandimport; demandimport.enable()
except ImportError:
    sys.stderr.write("abort: couldn't find mercurial libraries in [%s]\n" %
                     ' '.join(sys.path))
    sys.stderr.write("(check your install and PYTHONPATH)\n")
    sys.exit(-1)
```

You should be able to add the following path (D:\Python26\Lib\site-packages) in PYTHONPATH environment variable too.

This should allow python bundled with TortoiseHg to look at non-standard paths outside the bundled directory.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, could someone explain exactly where import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages'), should go? I'm using python27. I've added D:\Python27\  and D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib to my environment variables(windows). What should my mercurial.ini look like so far i've got activity=C:\myHgActivity\hgactivity-2.0\activity in it under [extensions]. A little more detail would be of so much help to me.

Comment: @pyfun I have just had the exact same problem. Although I added the site packages to PYTHONPATH it still refuses to work. After hacking away those stupid pokemon exception handling blocks I get this error: No module named matplotlib.figure!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is super late. I ended up installing python 2.7, and running hg from the command line

After installing python and adding it to your path, run the following commands from the windows commands prompt:

```
python -m pip install -U pip setuptools
python -m pip install matplotlib
python -m pip install mercurial
```

After that clone hgactivity

```
hg clone http://sources.freehackers.org/Hgactivity/
```

Then add it to your mercurial.ini file:

```
[extensions]
activity = C:\Repos\Hgactivity\activity
```

And now from the command line you should be able to do this:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\hg activity --help
```

Hope that helps.