# Difficulty installing and using Mercurial Chart extension

Tags: python, windows, mercurial, tortoisehg-2.0

Hi I'm having trouble installing and using the [Mercurial ChartExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ChartExtension)

When I installed it as per instructions

> First you need to install the extension; type this in your shell:
>     python ./setup.py install
>   Blockquote

[image: Install Results]

I then modified my mercurial.ini file as follows

> [extensions]
>     chart=/path/to/chart.py
>   Blockquote

Then tried running Hg Chart command and got the following error

[image: Hg Chart Error Message]

Can anyone help me get this extension working. I know there's the Hg ActivityExtension as well, but i have not had much luck with that either [Problem installing Mercurial Activity extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052768/problem-installing-mercurial-activity-extension?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

A layman's guide to what steps i need to follow would be of immense help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [changelog](https://bitbucket.org/Ry4an/hg-chart-extension/src), the Chart extension has not been updated since late 2008.  It would probably work if you tried using it with a version of Mercurial released around that same time (Mercurial v1.1.2 was released on Dec. 30, 2008).

The latest version of Mercurial is now v1.9.2.  The API has changed (probably quite a bit) since v1.1.2.  If the extension has not been modified to keep up with the changes to the API, then it will fail in ways similar to the error you found.  In this case, the number of arguments for the `walkchangerevs` method has changed.

Updating the extension could be a large task...there is no way to know without inspecting the code.  You could try to contact the author (@Ry4an) and ask for help.  You could also try to modify the extension yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I've not touched chart in a long while and I suspect it doesn't work with modern Mercurial.  Updating it should take very little time, but it's never quite made it to the top of the project pile.  It began as a fork of the 'churn' extension, so you could probably start there.